# How to add multiple functions in beforeShowDay?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi For complete project demo [click here](http://developmentarea.webassociates.co.in/JT-project2/index2.php). There you can find two test box one arrival and another is departure after selecting the dates below 6 months calender need change the color of selected date range. As add some code to hide some dates because that color change is not working.Below is my piece of code check once

```
 $('#end_date').datepicker(
{   minDate: 0,
   beforeShow: customRange,
   beforeShowDay:  function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
 },
   dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
   changeYear: true,
   onSelect:test

 });
 });
function test(input){
var array = unavailableDates;
$('.calendar').datepicker({beforeShowDay:function(date){
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#start_date").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#end_date").val());
            return [true, date1 <= date && date <= date2  ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
        }}).datepicker('refresh');
```

}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2dy7fug6/1/

Comment: i tryed it but i am getting error  "Unexpected literal at position 2"